# Converting SQL Server queries to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I am trying to convert the following SQL Server T-SQL block to a PostgreSQL compatible one using, preferably CTE or a function. The issue with converting is I am not able to figure out how I return the last inserted id (`scope_identity()` in SQL Server returns the last inserted id in the identity column).

```
 IF (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT p_id
            FROM qr_request
            WHERE q_ota = 'Done'
                            )
        )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO qr_request (
        u_id
        ,c_id
        ,r_id
        ,q_ota
        )
    VALUES (
        1
        ,2
        ,3
        ,'P'
        )

    COMMIT

    SELECT Scope_Identity() AS id
        ,p.email AS n
    FROM person p
    WHERE p.uid = 33
        AND deleted = 0
        
END
ELSE
    SELECT NULL AS id
        ,p.email AS n
    FROM person p
    WHERE p.uid = 33
        AND deleted = 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since PostgreSQL doesn't use the same traditional "ID" concept on Tables like SQL Server, rather it uses Sequences, getting the last value is a little different but there are a multitude of ways to do so as noticed in this well versed [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944481/5059085).

Specifically the functions you can leverage are [CURRVAL and LASTVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

Relevant info from the aforementioned and linked StackOverflow answer:

**`CURRVAL()`**:

```
INSERT INTO persons (lastname,firstname) VALUES ('Smith', 'John');
  SELECT currval('persons_id_seq');
```

> The name of the sequence must be known. Caveat: currval() only works
> after an INSERT (which has executed nextval() ), in the same session.

**`LASTVAL()`**:

> This is similar to the previous, only that you don't need to specify
> the sequence name: it looks for the most recent modified sequence
> (always inside your session, same caveat as above.)

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to create a sequence first?

Comment: @Rahul: no. If you define the column as `generated always as identity`, Postgres will automatically manage the sequence for you

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name indicates, it's a similar concept to ID in SQL Server, mostly just semantically different. But the concept of IDENTITY carries across database systems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that changes the design, right? I can't do that. What if the column doesn't already have **generated always as identity** ?

Comment: @Rahul: well, if you migrate an `identity` column from SQL Server to Postgres you will have to rewrite the DDL you use. Part of that migration will be the change from `identity` to `generated always as identity` (or the discouraged `serial` definition)

Comment: @Rahul I'll add, if it's not already an identity column then you won't be able to get the last ID that was generated. The same is true in SQL Server. The SCOPE_IDENTITY() function only works on Tables where the column is defined as an IDENTITY. Otherwise this too would not be doable in SQL Server.

Comment: I got it. But there is a caveat. The table where insertion happens is different from the table from which we are trying to return the last inserted id if you look carefully(I know that may sound weird)

Comment: @Rahul: `scope_identity()` [is defined as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "*Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope*" as no insert happened to the person table, the value returned can only be the one from `qr_request`

Comment: Thanks everyone. This https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281511/converting-sqlserver-queries-to-postgresql#comment550325_281513 would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no IF in SQL (or Postgres), I would rewrite this to use a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with new_request as (
  INSERT INTO qr_request (u_id,c_id,r_id,q_ota)
  select * 
  from ( VALUES (1,2,3,'P') ) as x(u_id,c_id,r_id,q_ota)
  where not exists (SELECT p_id
                    FROM qr_request
                    WHERE q_ota = 'Done')
  returning id --<< returns the generated ID if an INSERT happened
) 
select nr.id, 
       p.email AS n
FROM person p
  left join new_request nr on true
WHERE p.uid = 33
  AND deleted = 0
;
```

---

Obviously `qr_request.id` must be defined such that it automatically generates a new value during insert. The recommended way to do this, is using `generated always as identity`. So if you have this in SQL Server:

```
create table qr_request
(
  id   integer identity primary key
  u_id integer, 
  c_id integer, 
  r_id integer, 
  q_ota varchar(5)
);
```

you would use the following in Postgres:

```
create table qr_request
(
  id   integer primary key generated always as identity
  u_id integer, 
  c_id integer, 
  r_id integer, 
  q_ota varchar(5)
);
```

Comment: doesn't  returning id  here looks like it is being returned from new_request ? The original query has scope_identity() being returned from person

Comment: @Rahul: but the insert was done into `qr_request` so `scope_identity()` can only return the generated "ID" from that table, not from the person table.

Comment: are you saying that the query I shared will return the "id" from qr_request and not person table ?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens

Comment: Ok. Thanks  a_horse_with_no_name